# Websphere MQ Managed File Transfer Agents

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I’m new to MQ.  I have successfully installed WebSphere MQ, setup the queue managers, queues and channels between the queue managers. I have set up agents and I can start, stop and successfully ping the agents but the agents are not listed as shown on the attached screen shot. I have been trying to make the agents work so that I can test file transfer and set it up in our environment.
I even tried to create new coordination and command queue managers and no luck. I even tried the fteListAgents -p (coordination queue manager) and -v
I will really appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

What is the user id you are logged into machine as? Is it `Administrator` (on Windows)? If so you may be hitting the 12 character user id issue. Administrator is 13 character long and the 'r' at the end may be getting chopped off.  I recommend you to look at this troubleshooting [link.](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/list_agents_pd.htm)

Comment: Hi Shashi, that my be the issue I my user ID is 15 characters long. I will test and revert and also look at the link. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Shashi, Thanks it worked like a charm I'm using a windows user ID with 9 characters long. Thanks again

Comment: In that case could you please accept my response as answer?That will help to increase my reputation. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

If your windows user id is longer than 12 character, check this out:
1) Agents are started, but MQ Explorer agent list is empty?
2) Check under Queuemanager->YOURQM->Subscriptions -> User. Do you see your windows user name truncated to 12 characters?
3) Create a new windows user, with the user name as the 12 characters trancated user.
4) Add this 12 characters username to the Admin group.

Comment: The agents and QMgr should *never* be run as Windows Administrator due to the security issues.  Nor should the service accounts for these components be in the administrators group.  However, +1 for the ID length advice.

Answer (score 0):

MQ FTE used the queued PubSub mechanism.  Usually this problem happens because the ID being used doesn't have access to publish.  The procedure to diagnose this is as follows:

- Download the [MS0P SupportPac](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0P) and install it into WMQ Explorer.
- Enable authorization events on the Coordination Qmgr.
- Stop and restart an agent or two.
- Open MQ Explorer to the queues panel and find the SYSTEM.ADMIN.QMGR.EVENT queue.
- Right click on the queue and select "Format Event Messages."
- You should find some auths errors.

If the problem is authorization failures MS0P will tell you exactly which ID MQ thinks was used, the API call that failed and the object it failed on.